# TinyMCE local file upload handling with Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, tinymce-4

I am new to using Django. And I would like to customize TinyMCE editor for myself. I downloaded it and added to the project as a third part library, did not install it through pip. As you know, there is no free local file uploader in TinyMCE. And I'd like to do 3 things: **local image uploder, local audio/video uploader, and local file uploader**(with any extension(.pdf, .c, .cpp), this is like how you add a file at the end of a post so that users can download it). And during the realization I had the following issues.

1. I implemented the local image uploader with TinyMCE file_picker_callback(), and everything works fine. I can upload and edit photos locally, and all of this is displayed on the view page template. The path of each image is recorded in the textarea field in MySQL DB as src atribute. Whether each image should be uploaded(copied) to the MEDIA folder of the site or in a separate field in the MySQL DB. And how it can be implemented, how to write and call the python handler in the js file?
2. And I still do not download audio / video files. It seems for this in js file, after pressing the button it is necessary to wrap them in the appropriate HTML5 audio/video tags. Then, like the images, copy to the database or Media folder. I also don’t know how to write a Python handler and call it in js.
3. To upload files, I made my custom plugin and added it to TinyMCE. In plugin I created an input element and stopped there.

Now I have been suffering from it for a month, but I really want to do it. Because having made one full-featured text editor, you can use it many times in other projects. And I think that it needs to many people. If there are interested, then we could realize it together. 
There are php handlers on the Internet. But Python handlers for this purpose, I did not find. Any help and tips are welcome. I use Django 2.0.8 and python 3.6. The editor is in the admin panel.

My models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_author")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created", "-updated"]
```

admin.py:

```
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["title", "updated", "created"]
    list_display_links = ["title"]
    list_filter = ["created", "tags"]
    search_fields = ["title", "content",]
    form = MyTextForm
    class Meta:
        model = Post

    class Media:
        js = ('js/tinymce/tinymce.js', 'js/init-tinymce.js',
              '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js',)

admin.site.register(Post, PostModelAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
class MyTextForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'tinymce', 'label' : 'Content'}),
        }
```

And in the DB images stored as(into the content field):

```
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgH/2Q==" alt="" width="439" height="604"/></p>
```

Comment: This question is a bit too broad as formulated now. You need to show us the relevant parts of the code you have that cause you issues. When you say you're able to upload files (and store the path in the db), I assume you're using a `FileField` or `ImageField` on your Django model so it sounds like it's working. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: ok, so currently TinyMCE is just putting the image inline into your content field. If you want to upload your files properly and reference them as URL, you should look at [this](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/) and for the Django side [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/). You probably want to create an `attachment` model with a `ImageField` or `FileField` and ForeignKey to `Post`. Then create a view that receives the ajax post from tinymce and saves the attachment and returns the `location` parameter of the attachment.

Comment: Note that there is the *django-tinymce* package that together with *django-filebrowser* already does everything.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried all the ready applications TinyMCE. None of them satisfied me. And in the end I came to the conclusion to do everything from scratch. For example, django-tinymce does not support tinymce 4(tinymce 3 used in it, has a terrible design). With installation of tinymce4-lite i had many errors.

Comment: Makes sense. The Django part is not very difficult anyway. Creating a couple of views to handle the Ajax requests to save and delete images is all you need. I’ve done something similar for redactor.

Comment: Thanks you. I will try to do everything as you said. Yes, that's right, it's not too difficult. When I succeed, I will write about it.

Comment: Have you succeeded? @Bakytzhan

Comment: @VineethSai Yes, with the download everything worked out for me.
Now I am considering how to delete these files from the server when you delete them from the editor. And this is a bit of a challenge.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have installed django-tinymce and django-filebrowser, but local uploading images doesn't work. Could you help? I need to specify 'images_upload_url'? Which one?